# Adding a VBA macro to powerpoint

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

I am trying to create a new macro in powerpoint programmatically using interop.powerpoint

I have tried using Presentation object but the VB Project property only contains get attribute.

```
PowerPoint.Application oPP = new PowerPoint.Application()
        {
            DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpAlertLevel.ppAlertsNone,
            Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue
        };

        PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = oPP.Presentations;
        PowerPoint._Presentation _activePres = oPresSet.Open(@"‪C:\Users\Mohit\Desktop\Archive\Working_Session_S&OP.pptx",
        MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse,
        MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

I want to send the VBA macro code from C#

Answer (score 0):

you can create macro from interop project using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop reference and the next code(in this case to add macro on new opened presentation):

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.PresentationOpen += pres =>
        {
            var presentationVb = pres.VBProject;
            var vbComponent = presentationVb.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
            var vbComponentCodeModule = vbComponent.CodeModule;

            var lineNum = vbComponentCodeModule.CountOfLines + 1;
            var codeText = "Public Sub Test(link as String)" + "\r\n";
            //any VBA code
            codeText += "End Sub";

            vbComponentCodeModule.InsertLines(lineNum, codeText);
            pres.Save();
        };
    }
```